# derivative of the Real and imaginary parts of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have read in Ahlfors’ complex analysis (p23):

> “a real function of a complex variable either has the derivative zero, or else the derivative does not exist.”

and on p26:

> “if $u$ and $v$ have continuous first order partial derivatives which satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations, then $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ is analytic with continuous derivative $f ’(z)$ and conversely.”

Now from Rudin’s book I know, that the derivative of a function g : ${\rm I\!R^n \longrightarrow \rm I\!R^m}$ exists and is continuous, if and only if the first order partial derivatives exist and are continuous.

Now my thoughts were: if $u$ and $v$ have continuous first order partial derivatives, it must follow from the latter theorem, that their derivatives $u’(z)$ and $v’(z)$ exist. But since they are both real valued functions of a complex variable, Ahlfors’ book would suggest that their derivatives must then be zero, which would mean that their partial derivatives are zero as well.

Now I know that this is wrong and I must have misunderstood something, but I don’t understand where I’ve made my mistake. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Each of the theorems is talking about a different type of derivative. The one on page $23$ is taking about complex derivative. The one on page $26$ is talking about the existence of the complex derivative of $f$ given a condition on the partial (real in particular) derivatives of $u$ and $v$. The theorem from Rudin is probably talking about the existence of the differential (which maybe some people call derivative to its matrix).

Comment: So, given that $u,v$ have continuous partial derivatives, it doesn't follow that they have complex derivative. It only follows that $f=u+iv$ does.